# Replace image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to replace an image on button click but I don't seem to figure it out. I get an image from my server that looks like this `photo/1583testImg.png` from my ajax value. I wan't now to replace the current photo with the one that i get from the server through ajax.

```
 for(file in search){
    var title = search[file].title;
    var photo = search[file].path;
    $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").find("h3").text(title);
    $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").find("src").replace(photo); // this is the codeline that doesn't work
    console.log(title+"+"+photo);
}
```

Comment: Why you are cloning it twice?

Comment: Hm good question, I suppose I could just clone it once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change:

```
$(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").find("src").replace(photo);
```

to:

```
$(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").attr("src",photo);
```

if you need to display full path, you can use some options:

```
//window.location.host //you'll get sub.domain.com:8080 or sub.domain.com:80
//window.location.hostname ////you'll get sub.domain.com
//window.location.protocol : you'll get http:
//window.location.port //you'll get 8080 or 80
//window.location.pathname //you'll get /virtualPath

var mainUrl =  window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname;

$(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").attr("src",mainUrl+"/img/"+photo);
```

this will give you `http://example.com/img/photo/1583testImg.png`

Comment: Oh yea this worked, Can I ask one more thing, Since I get the photo from my server, how do I actually display it, since I get back the path from the server where the photo is, as in `photo/testImg.png`. Surley I can't just add it to the srcs?

Comment: do u want display full path? something like `http://example.com/img/photo/testImg.png` instead `photo/testImg.png` ?

Comment: Hm yea that might work, since I can use the url to view it on my browser. But doesnt seem to work to just add `attr("src","http://example.com/img/"+photo);`

Comment: yes u can, i edited the answer with the solution, edit to your own structure

Comment: Ye I tried this with my server (that is up and running, can view the images by the url) I tried to just paste it in the html and it worked, but the appendTo and just append the new picture didnt work (hard coded) as in `clone.appendTo(".search").attr("src", "http://www.mindshiftinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/test-big.png");` So I think the replacing codeline doesn't work correctly

Comment: can you use the element inspector from your navigator and take a look to what url is giving?

Comment: Never mind, it works now. Your code worked, it was my fault. I did a stupid mistake. Thanks for the help!